# How to take data from variable and put it into another

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

i'm having a little bit of an issue:
I would like to take this data,

```
for item in g_data:
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"})[0]["href"]
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"})[1]["href"]
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"})[2]["href"]
    print item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"})[3]["href"]
```

and use the results in another process.

The code currently prints out the urls of the first page of an amazon search term, I would like to take those urls and then scrape the data on the page. How would I go about making it so that it would be something like this:

If `for item in g_data` returns `url`, taker `url[1:15]` and do 'x' with
it.

If `for item in g_data` does not return url, say `"No urls to work with"`.

Any help or leads you could give would be great, thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take each item in `g_data`, find all urls in the item and if there are any, do x with them, if there are no urls in the item, then just print something, then this should work:

```
def do_x(url):
    """ Does x with the given url. """
    short = url[1:15]
    # do x with short
    # ...

# process all items in g_data
for item in g_data:
    # find all links in the item
    links = item.contents[1].find_all("a", {"class":"a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"})

    if not links:
        # no links in this item -> skip
        print("No urls to work with.")
        continue

    # process all links
    for link in links:
        urls = link["href"]
        # process each url
        for url in urls:
            do_x(url)
```

Is this what you wanted?